# The feasibility of making a body building machine

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, body-modification

I’ll try to explain this as short but as defined as I can.

Say one day in the not too distant future, mankind has finally figured out a medicine or treatment that slows down ageing. Familiess have more time to connect, old people don’t have to worry about death for a good while, you know, the positives. But, a scientist who is too old to take the medicine, thinks of making a machine that can build bodies.

The machine itself is as big and tall as a elephant. The purpose of this machine is to build entire bodies, not for just enjoyment, but because he wants to build a body that won’t die of age.

The machine itself is capable of building the entire nervous system, organs, muscles, and skin, and the entire process is done inside a clear capsule filled with fluid that simulates the inside of a womb.
The machine is also capable of creating a clone of the person, but that would require a viable dna sample. The machine is, however, incapable or creating a consciousness for the body’s, nor is it capable of transferring entire consciousness into said created body, it’s also incapable of making a body any drastic additions or modifications such wings or bullet proof skin.

What the question is asking:

1. Is it feasible for such a complex machine to ever exist?
2. If not, what’s the closest thing we’ve gotten to a body making machine?

The part were the scientist tries to transfer his consciousness into the new body might be asked, depending if the consciousness transfer question has already been asked.

Comment: Building a new brain is going to be problematic, no?

Comment: @StarfishPrime you don't need a brain to function. Just look at <insert group of people to mock for their stupidity here>!

Comment: Greetings! I see that you're still pretty new and that your question is suffering from confused writing and is in danger of being closed due to lack of focus. I'd invite you to review the [tour] and the [help] so you can gain a better understanding of how to write a good, focused query. (cont)

Comment: I'd get rid of the fluff: you don't need to compare your machine with a pachyderm; you don't need to tell me about families getting together. Just get to the point: clean up the paragraph that describes what you want the machine to do and finish up with your two-part query. Also, kindly cut the bit about transferring consciousness. That's irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: Note if the machine can create a brain it can create a consciousness, it might not be the same consciousness,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Reality Check = *FEASIBLE!*

Already, even now in the early 21st century, so many of the pieces your machine requires are on the table in front of us. Printing of biological substrates is being worked on and I think functional organs and tissues won't be far behind.

The technology for keeping organs actually alive, rather than slowly dying on ice, before transplant is nascent. Essentially, a portable heart-lung machine is connected to the organ for transport.

Bioengineered bone, nerve and vessel tissues are also becoming a reality.

Obviously, now in 2020 we're nowhere close to devising a "body making machine", but quite a few of the basic pieces are already in play. Numerous hurdles remain, but I think the overall goal is certainly feasible within a reasonable time frame.

Comment: Bah, everyone is printing bones and livers and stuff... what I want is some new cartilage. Apparently that's too much to ask though >:-(

Comment: @StarfishPrime not anymore https://aabme.asme.org/posts/3d-bioprinting-grows-bone-cartilage

Answer (score 1):

The reason why organisms die is because death by accident or misadventure is so common in nature that life expectancy tends to be quite limited. In such an environment, a gene that provided an advantage to young adults but caused damaged to the old would flourish because so few people would live to old age anyway.

So it might be possible to build a body that would not die of old age, however we would have to possess an almost godlike knowledge of all possible human genes and their effects throughout a human life time. It might then be possible to remove or modify the genes that cause old age, it might be necessary to add a lot more additional genes to repair damage that occurs as well.

BUT the task is unimaginably difficult. We have hardly started: should a complex task if possible at all could take thousands or even millions of years to come to fruition.

Comment: Eh, I don't know about "_unimaginably difficult_" or "_thousands of years_". Getting to space would have seemed like that to pre-industrial folk, but here we are, only a few hundred years later. It is irrelevant to the question anyway, as you don't need to build an immortal body if you can do mind transfer...

Comment: Mind transfer is not part of the question. IMO unimaginably difficult as things stand today, maybe someone will make a series of breakthroughs in the future and it will happen, maybe they won't. Traveling at faster than the speed of light would have be seen as impossible to people just a few hundred years ago and it is still impossible today as far as we know, maybe that will change maybe not.

Comment: Sure, its a load of cobblers, but it _is_ mentioned in the question.